# Problem with proguard...(no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object

Tags: android, proguard

The debug of my app everything works but when I run the release, I have a problem
In the logcat I have the message:

Cannot construct instance of `com.my.myapp.MiClaseDatosPrincipalesTiempoGeocodingAPI$Root` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

I added an empty constructor in the class, but the problem persists.
I also tried annotate constructor parameters with @JsonProperty("field_name")
(since it didn't work, I left it as before.)

```
public class MiClaseDatosPrincipalesTiempoGeocodingAPI {

    public MiClaseDatosPrincipalesTiempoGeocodingAPI(){

    }

    public static class LocalNames{
        @Keep
        public String et;
        public String is;
        public String fr;
        public String ba;
        public String br;
        public String os;
        public String ht;
        public String mk;

//some code

     }

     public static class Root{
        @Keep
        public String name;
        public LocalNames local_names;
        public double lat;
        public double lon;
        public String country;
        public String state;
    }
}
```

my proguard rules:

```
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.*

-keep class com.my.myapp.**{<fields>;}


-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
-dontwarn org.springframework.**

-keep class androidx.annotation.Keep {*;}
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.*
```

My gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.10'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.1.0-beta02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2")
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.1'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.1'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.7.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:' + lifecycle_version
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:' + lifecycle_version

}
```